# Apache Pig - Determining and loading the latest dataset in a directory

Tags: hdfs, apache-pig

I have an hdfs location with several timestamped directories and I need my pig script to pick up the latest one. For example

```
/projects/ABC/dailydata/20170110/
/projects/ABC/dailydata/20170115/
/projects/ABC/dailydata/20170203/ #<---- pig should pick this one
```

What I've tried is and got working is below, but wondering if there's a cleaner way to get the latest timestamp

```
sh hdfs dfs -ls /projects/ABC/dailydata/ | tail -1
```

Comment: you can write hdfs commands in pig script - this is fine and fast to get what you want. Consider the more general case, you may want to consider using Oozie which have what you need build-in into the framework

Comment: Thanks Mzf. I went ahead and used oozie's builtin methods for data availability.